# LDAP TLS doesn't work even though gnutls-cli works

Tags: ldap, ssl

I'm trying to set up LDAP client access using TLS. I've added the certificates of my CA and both gnutls and openssl connect just fine to the LDAP server. When I try ldapsearch though it still says `TLS: peer cert untrusted or revoked`

As said: connecting with gnutls-cli results in `Peer's certificate is trusted`. I've set `tls_cacertfile /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates` in my LDAP configuration and this is the same cacert file I use when I tried connecting with gnutls-cli and openssl.

This rules out any source of error I've found on this topic so far

Where can I go from here?

Thanks

edit: gnutls version is 2.8.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*derp* Just came along something by chance... the correct configuration directive is `tls_cacert` and not `tls_cacertfile` as the default config file indicates